# transfer vm machine created in virtualbox to vmware player

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, vmware-player

```
Fedora 17 Host
Oracle VirtualBox 4.2.4
Vmware Player 5.0.1 build-894247
```

I have Fedora 17 and have installed Virtualbox and vmware player.

I created a CentOS virtual machine guest in virtual box. Using the vmdk disk image format. I have the following files in my VirtualBox VM directory.

```
CentOS_5_6_svr2_x86_64.vbox
CentOS_5_6_svr2_x86_64.vbox-prev
CentOS_5_6_x86_64-flat.vmdk
CentOS_5_6_x86_64.vmdk
```

However, I have decided to use Vmware player. I don't want to have to create a new virtual machine over again. Is it possible to open these files in vmware player without having create a new virtual machine?

In vmware player I only have options to open an exiting virtual machine or create a new one.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, though I wouldn't recommend it.  You're introducing unknowns into your server environment which will probably come back to bit you down the line.  Having said that, there are a couple guides out there that do a good job of explaining it.  [This one at How to Geek is short and sweet](http://www.howtogeek.com/125640/how-to-convert-virtual-machines-between-virtualbox-and-vmware/), and [this one at TechRepublic is more in-depth](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/how-do-i-convert-virtualbox-files-to-work-with-vmware-workstation/2997) (plus, I have trouble taking How to Geek seriously).  Oh, and don't use VMWare player na  professional environment anyway.  Use ESXi/ESX, or if you must, Workstation.

The basic steps are:

1. Export the VM through Virtual Box <kbd>File</kbd> --> <kbd>Export Appliance</kbd> into OVA or OVF format.
2. Import into VMWare.

Depending on your versions, and tolerance for errors in the imported VM, you may wish to edit your OVA/OVF with a text editor and/or use a VMWare tool to convert the OVA/OVF to a `.vmx`.