# Is it possible to import VirtualBox 4.2.12 exported OVA file into VMWare ESX 4?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-esx, vmware-workstation, export, import

I have created an OVA file from VirtualBox 4.2.12, and someone tried to import this ova file into VMWare ESX 4. When he was doing so, VMWare ESX 4 promopted:

```
Line 25: Unsupported hardware family 'virtualbox-2.2'.
```

I assumed that the OVA file can be universally imported into VirtualBox, VMWare Workstation and VMWare ESX, but now it turned out not the case.

Now, step back a little, I want to know: Is it possible to create from VirtualBox VM, an OVA or OVF file that can be imported into all of the following product without error?

1. VMware Workstation 6 or above?
2. VMware ESX 4 or above?
3. VirtualBox 4.2.12 or above?

Comment: why are you using such old versions? they're bound to impact on portability options.

Comment: I have checked the closed question http://serverfault.com/questions/448056/transfer-vm-machine-created-in-virtualbox-to-vmware-player , and not sure if there are better answers, so I started another question.

Comment: @Chopper3, which version of VirtualBox do you suggest I use?

Comment: `Something Like` isn't really good enough; messages are there for a reason. I think Chopper3 is referring to the old version of ESX not VB.

Comment: I will verify that information, thanks for your help!

Comment: and here is the ticket found on VirtualBox official site, I didn't find a solution there: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7982

Comment: @PIMGeek - as suggested I did indeed mean the 3+ year old versions of ESXi (5.5 is the latest) and Workstation (9 is the latest) - both significantly improve on importing options.

Comment: @Chopper3 Thanks very much for being helpful. :) We were trying to satisfy some clients who insist on using old version... We ourselves usually use the latest stable versions. (And sorry for having asked amateur-style question here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [article](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2012352) on VMware knowledge base trying to explain a similar issue but on ESXi 5.x.

Try to modify the XML manifest of your OVA/OVF appliance:

1. Open the OVA/OVF file in some editor
2. Search for the XML Tag `<VirtualSystemType>virtualbox2.2</VirtualSystemType>`
3. As you want to import it to ESX 4, replace the string `virtualbox2.2` with `vmx-06`
4. Try import again

Comment: I used `vmx-08` for ESXi 5.5. (as it is not retro-compatible with `vmx-06`, strangely enough)